# How to validate a phone number doesn't contain any other characters including - and . using javascript in a html page, shouldnt be less than 10 digits

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, adobe-campaign-classic

This is in Adobe campaign classic.

`type="text" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}"`

It is allowing only 10 digits, but accepting `-` and `.`
I want the user to enter only 10 not less or more and accept only digits.
Please help.

Comment: you can use a regex for that

Answer (score 1):

You can always sanitize the input using a javascript piece of code.
But as you are asking for a validation, simply use a numeric HTML input with max and min attributes.

E.g.

```
<input type="number" min="1000000000" max="9999999999">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to replace non-numeric characters(`\D`) after user input:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="tel"]')].forEach(i =>
  i.addEventListener('input', () => i.value = i.value.replace(/\D/g, ''))
);
```

```html
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}" />
```